# How to resolve background image css issue in IE

Tags: css

Tried to set background image for body's id.Below the css is not working in IE.It is working only in chrome and firefox but not working in IE.How to resolve this issue.If anyone know please help to find solution.

HTML:

```
<body id="bg"></body>
```

CSS:

```
#bg{
background:url(/test/images/bg.png) repeat scroll 0 0;
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Does this help?
https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/mrkdilkington-full-screen-background-image-and-overlay/support/background-image-not-showing-on-internet-explorer-10-11-for-wind/

Comment: @AhmadHabib: What add -on?

Comment: Give html a white background. It might stick the bg in body and not send it to <html>